# Azure Form Recognizer - to read all PDF files(Custom format)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Can anyone point/guide me as to how to use a Trained model to extract data from custom PDF using Azure form recognizer via Python. I have the Python code that the trained model has generated. I then used it by setting the correct parameters but unfortunately I am not able to successfully read this. Any pointers please.

(Note - I have been through all StackOverflow related questions but none of them answers it clearly on my scenario)

```
This code sample shows Custom Extraction Model operations with the Azure Form Recognizer client library. 
The async versions of the samples require Python 3.6 or later.

To learn more, please visit the documentation - Quickstart: Form Recognizer Python client library SDKs
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/get-started-v3-sdk-rest-api?view=doc-intel-3.1.0&pivots=programming-language-python
"""

from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient

"""
Remember to remove the key from your code when you're done, and never post it publicly. For production, use
secure methods to store and access your credentials. For more information, see 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-security?tabs=command-line%2Ccsharp#environment-variables-and-application-configuration
"""
endpoint = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT"
key = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_KEY"

model_id = "YOUR_CUSTOM_BUILT_MODEL_ID"
formUrl = "YOUR_DOCUMENT"

document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
    endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
)

# Make sure your document's type is included in the list of document types the custom model can analyze
poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(model_id, formUrl)
result = poller.result()

for idx, document in enumerate(result.documents):
    print("--------Analyzing document #{}--------".format(idx + 1))
    print("Document has type {}".format(document.doc_type))
    print("Document has confidence {}".format(document.confidence))
    print("Document was analyzed by model with ID {}".format(result.model_id))
    for name, field in document.fields.items():
        field_value = field.value if field.value else field.content
        print("......found field of type '{}' with value '{}' and with confidence {}".format(field.value_type, field_value, field.confidence))


# iterate over tables, lines, and selection marks on each page
for page in result.pages:
    print("\nLines found on page {}".format(page.page_number))
    for line in page.lines:
        print("...Line '{}'".format(line.content.encode('utf-8')))
    for word in page.words:
        print(
            "...Word '{}' has a confidence of {}".format(
                word.content.encode('utf-8'), word.confidence
            )
        )
    for selection_mark in page.selection_marks:
        print(
            "...Selection mark is '{}' and has a confidence of {}".format(
                selection_mark.state, selection_mark.confidence
            )
        )

for i, table in enumerate(result.tables):
    print("\nTable {} can be found on page:".format(i + 1))
    for region in table.bounding_regions:
        print("...{}".format(i + 1, region.page_number))
    for cell in table.cells:
        print(
            "...Cell[{}][{}] has content '{}'".format(
                cell.row_index, cell.column_index, cell.content.encode('utf-8')
            )
        )
print("-----------------------------------")
```

[image: I am using below to read contents of my blob]

Comment: can you share your code, exactly what is the error?

Comment: Added the generated code to the actual post. I still trying to figure out how do I replace the formUrl. The Endpoint and key is fine - I got from Azure portal.

Comment: sure let me put an updated code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below I have commented about where the endpoint and URL from Azure.

replace these values - YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT, YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_API_KEY, YOUR_TRAINED_MODEL_ID, and the PDF path) with your actual values.

```html
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerApiVersion
import os

# Set your Azure Form Recognizer endpoint and API key
endpoint = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_ENDPOINT"
api_key = "YOUR_FORM_RECOGNIZER_API_KEY"

# Set the model ID for your trained model
model_id = "YOUR_TRAINED_MODEL_ID"

# Initialize the Form Recognizer client
form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(
    endpoint=endpoint,
    credential=AzureKeyCredential(api_key),
    api_version=FormRecognizerApiVersion.V2_1
)

# Specify the path to the PDF file you want to analyze
pdf_path = "path/to/your/custom.pdf"

# Extract data from the PDF using the trained model
with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
    poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_custom_forms(
        model_id=model_id,
        form=pdf_file,
        content_type="application/pdf"
    )
    result = poller.result()

# Output the extracted data
for recognized_form in result:
    for name, field in recognized_form.fields.items():
        print("Field: {} with value {}".format(name, field.value))
```

check this -

```html
https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/yourcontainer/yourfile.txt?<storage-account-key>
```

Comment: What I am still trying to figure out is the path to file. I have all the files stored in another container on azure. I want all of them to be read one by one. If I generate SAS token of a file, it is successfully read, but I cant just keep generating SAS token for all the files. So I am lost !

Comment: got it, instead of generating SAS tokens for individual files every time, you can generate a SAS token for the entire container in your case. This way, the token allows access to all files within that container. You can set the expiry of the SAS token too.   i will add the sample path in the end of original answer.

Comment: Does that mean I need to loop within the documents present in the container?

Comment: yes thats right.

Comment: So is it like loop for all the files and then keep using the trained model to extract the data?

Comment: yes, if you want to process or read multiple files from a container, you would need to iterate over the documents present in that container.

Comment: So how do I generate the form URL? I have the access string of the storage account. What should I append to it to make the complete formURL?

Comment: Added an iamge I am using to browse through the Blobs.